# How to root Vodafone Smart Prime 7 (VFD600)

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, supersu

buid number VDF-VFD600B01-IT02c
kernel version 3.10.49
android version 6.0.1

I tried to use KingRoot, but it didn't work, now I have on my Prime 7 the apps Purify and King User but the smartphone is not rooted.

I tried also with SuperSU Me but the application crashs.

I hope this informations will be useful, thanks a lot.

Comment: I've seen that you can't root that phone with the classics apps like KingRoot, maybe these two links can help you: (https://www.oneclickroot.com/vodafone/vodafone-smart-prime-7/)(https://www.oneclickroot.com/vodafone/vodafone-smart-prime-7/) or (http://rootkhp.pro/how-to-root-vodafone-smart-prime-7/)(http://rootkhp.pro/how-to-root-vodafone-smart-prime-7/)